# changing background color through Ajax jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

scenario: my users have their own profile pages with different background colors and fonts, I want to retrieve the colors for example from a certain user using ajax. i.e.

```javascript
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    data: "id", 
    url: "ajax/css.php", 
    success: function (bg,font) { 
        $('#bg').css('background-color', 'bg');
        $('#font').css('font-color', 'font');
    }
```

ajax/css.php page

```php
<?php

//retrieve the background and font data from database for the id(userID).

// this is the bit I'm stuck here, shall I echo the results or return them :~

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON would probably be easiest here, like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   data: { id: someIDVariable }, 
   url: "ajax/css.php", 
   success: function (result) { 
     $('#bg').css('background-color', result.bg);
     $('#font').css('font-color', result.font);
   } 
});
```

Or a shorter form using [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is GET is an option:

```
$.getJSON("ajax/css.php", { id: someID }, function (result) { 
  $('#bg').css('background-color', result.bg);
  $('#font').css('font-color', result.font);
});
```

Then in PHP:

```
eacho json_encode(array('font'=>$font,'bg'=>$bg));
//which will echo this format: { "font": "Arial", "bg": "#000000" }
```

Comment: thank you very much exactly what i needed cheers @nick you always save the day, by the way im using this example instead accessing iframes through subdomains its bit a wierd bu i think it will work

Comment: @getaway - ahh, good approach, *much* better than the alternative :) +1 for trying to do it efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Just make an action returning a valid JSON with the data you need. For instance if it returns:

```
{ color: "red", font:"arial"}
```

You can do:

```
$.post("user_css_info.json",{id:1234}, function(data){
  alert("Color is" + data.color); 
});
```

Comment: To make your php file return json: in your ajax script (php file), create an array of the data you want to return and then `echo json_encode($your_data_array);`

Comment: thanks for this @harldo thats where i was confused, can you just calrify where the user_css_info.json came from lool